# Add Chakra os benz to grub 1.99

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have Debian 7 with grub 1.99 in `sda1` and Chakra OS **without grub** in `sda2` I want to make a dual boot via grub 1,99, how?

Answer (score 0):

Grub 1 configuration is easier than grub 2, perhaps because with grub 1 they intended for users to edit the conf file directly themselves.  Have a [look here](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubConfiguration) for some general information and specifics about where to find the conf file on debian. `info grub` is the definitive reference, although if you do not use `info` much it takes a bit of patience.

You want to create a new section (starting with a "title" line) for Chakra on sda2.  While reading the link above, pay attention to the way grub identifies partitions *(it does not use "sda2")*.  There are three things that are critical:

```
root # The root filesystem device node, e.g. (hd0,1)
kernel # The path to the Chakra kernel relative to the root filesystem.
initrd # The path to the initial ramdisk used by the kernel to access
         critical modules at boot.  Virtually all modern distros use this,
         you have to figure out where it is (probably in the same directory
         as the kernel).
```